# which glue to repair kids floaties?

Tags: adhesive

I have some of these inflatable kids rubber rings, toys etc, I presume made of PVC, with little holes in them here and there, leaking air

some rips are close to the seam so I cannot put on a sticky patch. I think it is possible to put a "glue" on top of the little hole to seal it (without a patch). I read about MEK glues, but MEK is a solvent right? How can it glue anything?

What kind of glue would you recommend for this kind of repair? Must be

- water resistant
- stretchy (to resist inflation)

Another concern is the cost; these toys cost $5 or less so I don't want a glue that costs more than the toy! I would also prefer something that lasts for a few months once opened.

thank you for your recommendations
Nikos

PS. would plain superglue work on a small hole without a patch?

Comment: Just a note: Most plastic-specific glues are solvents. They work by dissolving a small amount of the substrate on each part, which then mixes, and solidifies again as a joined whole when the solvent evaporates. They most likely wouldn't work in a "blob-on" manner, as you say. Superglue is rigid, and quite brittle. It's unlikely it would do what you want.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

These are made from vinyl but not PVC. Same base chemical but different materials and different chemistry.

Go to any pool or outdoor water sports supply store and they will have inflatable vinyl repair kits with appropriate glue and patches.

No, cyanoacrylate adhesives (i.e. super-glue) will not hold well here.